# Not able to update to Polkadot0.9.18

Tags: polkadot

I am following this PR https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-parachain-template/pull/103 to upgrade codebase to `Polkadot 0.9.18` but facing the below issue

```
   Compiling cexpr v0.6.0
error[E0658]: trait bounds other than `Sized` on const fn parameters are unstable
   --> /home/deployer/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/crossbeam-epoch-0.9.8/src/atomic.rs:314:6
    |
314 | impl<T: ?Sized + Pointable> Atomic<T> {
    |      ^
...
346 |     pub const fn null() -> Atomic<T> {
    |     -------------------------------- function declared as const here
    |
    = note: see issue #93706 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/93706> for more information
    = help: add `#![feature(const_fn_trait_bound)]` to the crate attributes to enable

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0658`.
error: could not compile `crossbeam-epoch` due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

Can someone please help me to fix this? Here is code https://github.com/DataHighway-DHX/DataHighway-Parachain/tree/change-para-id

```
installed toolchains

nightly-2022-02-23-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

wasm32-unknown-unknown
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-2022-02-23-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (directory override for '/home/deployer/Parachain')
rustc 1.61.0-nightly (68369a041 2022-02-22)
```

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade your rust toolchain? You can do that by `rustup update` and `rustup update nightly`

Answer (score 2):

I was able to update that repository to branch 'polkadot-v0.9.18' that is used by Cumulus and Substrate repositories and it compiled successfully in the PR [here](https://ttps://github.com/DataHighway-DHX/DataHighway-Parachain/pull/35).

The approach that I used to update it was to:

- Inspect the commit history of the [Cumulus repository branch 'polkadot-v0.9.17'](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/tree/polkadot-v0.9.17) and [Cumulus repository branch 'polkadot-v0.9.18'](https://github.com/paritytech/cumulus/tree/polkadot-v0.9.18) to find the latest commits that were included in branch 'polkadot-v0.9.18' but not in branch 'polkadot-v0.9.17'.
- Go through each of those latest commits in branch 'polkadot-v0.9.18', and incorporate changes in files that are within folders like: parachain-template/
- Since that repository is using additional pallets from Substrate that are not in the [substrate-node-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template) it may also be necessary to incorporate changes from [Substrate repository branch 'polkadot-v0.9.18'](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/polkadot-v0.9.18), however this may only required inspecting files in folders: ./bin/node/ and ./bin/node-template/